# How to use if else statement in objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, object, playwright

How to change below code to object structure. My aim is here I want to access nodID and xID keys from different files.But the problem is in below code there is a if statement.So I thought that if I use `export const testConfig ={}` and import testConfig from any file I can access to nodID and xId. But I don t know how can convert below code a object structure and access nodID and xID keys from different files.

```
    var env = process.env.ENV;
    if (!env) {
          env= "1";
       }
    if (env == '1') {
      nodID= 'aaaaaaa-f517-4859-91ff-bbbbbbbbb',
      xID='cccccc-f517-4859-91ff-nnnnnnnn'
     },
    else if (env == '2') {
      nodeID='cacacaca-7c96-441d-a3af-hththt'
      
    }
    else{
      nodeID='mlmlmlml-7c96-441d-a3af-frfrrfrrf'
    }
```

I would like to know if I have a different access option instead of the object structure?

Comment: What will `nodID` and `xID` be when `env` is not '1'?

Comment: You can always export a variable from a file, and then use it wherever you want or you can put them all in an object and then export it.

Comment: So you have cases where `xID` remains undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like this suit you ? or may be you want to edit your process.env to enrich new value ?

```js
// Create a proces.env.ENV variable in this snippet
const process = { env: { ENV: '1' } };
// Extract `ENV` from process.env and create a variable with this value called `env`
const { ENV: env } = process.env;
const toto = {
  ...((!env || env === '1') && {
    nodID: 'aaaaaaa-f517-4859-91ff-bbbbbbbbb',
    xID: 'cccccc-f517-4859-91ff-nnnnnnnn'
  })
};
console.log(toto);
```